# Convert string to integer within BotFramework Composer

Tags: c#, azure-language-understanding, bot-framework-composer

Yes, this is a common question, but how can you do it from within the Bot Framework Composer (v2.1.2)?  I've looked at the options in "Convert" as per the image in the link, but none seem to achieve it.

[Convert Options in Bot Framework Composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdrLl.png)

Essentially, I need to be able to obtain an integer, value e.g. 2 from e.g. "Two weeks". I have split the string into an array so have captured the "Two" but if I try int(string) it returns Null.  I have tried training LUIS to recognise a number, but all it does is recognise the number as a string, so same problem...  Thanks!

[LUIS @Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCimE.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to recognize an utterance and get an integer from that, then LUIS or NLP is the correct route. This would be best as something like "A couple of weeks" *may* also be recognized, and that would not contain the word `two`.

Conversion requires a bit less guessing and would work on something like converting `"2"` to `2`.

Can you please share what you have attempted with LUIS? Specific examples would be best.

Comment: I've used the @Number intent.  It recognises Three as a number, but the output is still "Three" not 3, which is what I need. Google's Dialog Flow enables you to train an entity to output a number rather than a string of letters.  I've saved an image in my original post - link is "Luis @Number". Thank you!

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, I think the only thing you can do at this point is either make an external API call, or have list/array/dictionary of words-to-int that was pre built and do a lookup. Unfortunately there's no way to do this with Composer, LUIS or adaptive expressions out of the box.